# configparser can't read regular config file, no section

Tags: python-3.x

configparser (Python 3.7) found no section in regular config file

I don't get why this code won't work, I checked every detail in the doc. What can be wrong with my cnf file format?

File /home/julien/Workspace/BnsManager/data/.secret/.paris.cnf

```
[ldap]
admin_dn=Directory Manager
admin_password=superpassword
```

Permissions on .secret folder

```sh
ls -la .secret/
drwxrwxr-x 2 julien julien 4096 oct.  16 15:51 .
drwxrwxr-x 6 julien julien 4096 oct.  16 15:42 ..
-rw-rw-r-- 1 julien julien   60 oct.  17 08:48 .paris.cnf
```

File test.py

```py
import configparser

p = '/home/julien/Workspace/BnsManager/data/.secret/.paris.cnf'
cp = configparser.ConfigParser()
cp.read(p)
print(cp.sections())
```

The ouput is [] but I expected it to be ['ldap']
Do you see what went wrong?

Comment: When I shortened the path and put config into paris.cnf in current directory, it worked as expected. What about permissions for the directories in the path?

Comment: Thanks, I edited my question to show permissions more clearly than in comment

Answer (score 1):

Try this to get the exception with explanation why the file is not read:

```
import configparser

p = '/home/julien/Workspace/BnsManager/data/.secret/.paris.cnf'
with open(p, 'r'):
  print('file could be opened')
cp = configparser.ConfigParser()
cp.read(p)
print(cp.sections())
```

Comment: My g... Thanks a lot! It was a case problem, the path was wrong